# Calling a v8 javascript function from c++ with an argument

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I am working with c++ and v8, and have run into the following challenge: I want to be able to define a function in javascript using v8, then call the function later on through c++. Additionally, I want to be able to pass an argument to the javascript function from c++. I think the following sample source code would explain it best. Check towards the end of the sample code to see what I am trying to accomplish.

```
#include <v8.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace v8;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
    HandleScope handle_scope;

    // Create a new context.
    Persistent<Context> context = Context::New();
    Context::Scope context_scope(context);
    Handle<String> source;
    Handle<Script> script;
    Handle<Value> result;

    // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
    source = String::New("function test_function(test_arg) { var match = 0;if(test_arg[0] == test_arg[1]) { match = 1; }");

    // Compile the source code.
    script = Script::Compile(source);

    // What I want to be able to do (this part isn't valid code..
    // it just represents what I would like to do.
    // An array is defined in c++ called pass_arg,
    // then passed to the javascript function test_function() as an argument
    std::array< std::string, 2 > pass_arg = {"value1", "value2"};
    int result = script->callFunction("test_function", pass_arg);

}
```

Any tips?

**UPDATE:**

Based on the advice given, I have been able to put together the following code. It has been tested and works:

```
#include <v8.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace v8;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

// Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
HandleScope handle_scope;

// Create a new context.
Persistent<Context> context = Context::New();

//context->AllowCodeGenerationFromStrings(true);

// Enter the created context for compiling and
// running the hello world script.
Context::Scope context_scope(context);
Handle<String> source;
Handle<Script> script;
Handle<Value> result;


// Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
source = String::New("function test_function() { var match = 0;if(arguments[0] == arguments[1]) { match = 1; } return match; }");

// Compile the source code.
script = Script::Compile(source);

// Run the script to get the result.
result = script->Run();
// Dispose the persistent context.
context.Dispose();

// Convert the result to an ASCII string and print it.
//String::AsciiValue ascii(result);
//printf("%s\n", *ascii);

Handle<v8::Object> global = context->Global();
Handle<v8::Value> value = global->Get(String::New("test_function"));
Handle<v8::Function> func = v8::Handle<v8::Function>::Cast(value);
Handle<Value> args[2];
Handle<Value> js_result;
int final_result;

args[0] = v8::String::New("1");
args[1] = v8::String::New("1");

js_result = func->Call(global, 2, args);
String::AsciiValue ascii(js_result);

final_result = atoi(*ascii);

if(final_result == 1) {

    std::cout << "Matched\n";

} else {

    std::cout << "NOT Matched\n";

}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: I assume that IsInt32 returns true, but Int32Value returns 0?

Comment: Check out my edit -- maybe we're not passing enough parameters...

Comment: You have a mistake in your code: you dispose the current context and after you are using it. You must put the dispose line at the end of your program.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it's possible that something like this will work:

```
// ...define and compile "test_function"

Handle<v8::Object> global = context->Global();
Handle<v8::Value> value = global->Get(String::New("test_function")); 

if (value->IsFunction()) {
    Handle<v8::Function> func = v8::Handle<v8::Function>::Cast(value);
    Handle<Value> args[2];
    args[0] = v8::String::New("value1");
    args[1] = v8::String::New("value2");

    Handle<Value> js_result = func->Call(global, 2, args);

    if (js_result->IsInt32()) {
        int32_t result = js_result->ToInt32().Value();
        // do something with the result
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

It looks like your javascript function expects a single argument (consisting of an array of two values), but it kinda looks like we're calling `func` by passing in two arguments.

To test this hypothesis, you could change your javascript function to take two arguments and compare them, e.g.:

```
function test_function(test_arg1, test_arg2) { 
  var match = 0; 
  if (test_arg1 == test_arg2) { 
    match = 1; 
  } else { 
    match = 0; 
  } 
  return match; 
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working. I'm having trouble using js_result though. The part where it says if(js_result.IsInt32) is giving the following error during compile time: error: ‘class v8::Handle<v8::Value>’ has no member named ‘Int32’|

Comment: @user396404: maybe try `js_result->IsInt32()` instead?

Comment: That did work. The code compiles, but it is not returning a value of 1 even if the values match :/

Comment: Thanks for all the help. It turns out I had to reference the variables using the arguments array, instead of test_arg1 and test_arg2. For anyone reading this in the future, the part where it says Call(global, 2, args), the 2 represents the length of the args array. I posted the revised and working code in my original answer. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Any chance for an updated version of this code? It doesn't appear to compile with the V8 in 2018.

Answer (score 10):

For new version of v8, you can use `v8::Object::CallAsFunction` or `v8::Function::Call` to call a javascript function. Here is an example for recent version (7.4.x)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libplatform/libplatform.h>
#include <v8.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
    v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
    std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
    v8::V8::Initialize();

    v8::Isolate::CreateParams createParams;
    createParams.array_buffer_allocator = v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
    v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(createParams);

    std::cout << v8::V8::GetVersion() << std::endl;

    {
        v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
        v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

        v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate);
        v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);

        v8::Local<v8::String> source = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "var foo=function(){return 'foo get called';}");
        v8::Local<v8::Script> script = v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

        v8::TryCatch tryCatch(isolate);
        v8::MaybeLocal<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context);
        if (result.IsEmpty()) {
            v8::String::Utf8Value e(isolate, tryCatch.Exception());
            std::cerr << "Exception: " << *e << std::endl;
        } else {
            v8::String::Utf8Value r(isolate, result.ToLocalChecked());
            std::cout << *r << std::endl;
        }

        v8::Local<v8::Value> foo_value = context->Global()->Get(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "foo"));
        if (foo_value->IsFunction()) {
            v8::Local<v8::Value> foo_ret = foo_value->ToObject(isolate)->CallAsFunction(context, context->Global(), 0, nullptr).ToLocalChecked();
            v8::String::Utf8Value utf8Value(isolate, foo_ret);
            std::cout << "CallAsFunction result: " << *utf8Value << std::endl;

            v8::Local<v8::Object> foo_object = foo_value->ToObject(isolate);
            v8::Local<v8::Value> foo_result = v8::Function::Cast(*foo_object)->Call(context, context->Global(), 0, nullptr).ToLocalChecked();
            std::cout << "Call result: "  << *(v8::String::Utf8Value(isolate, foo_result)) << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "foo is not a function" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    isolate->Dispose();
    v8::V8::Dispose();
    v8::V8::ShutdownPlatform();
    delete createParams.array_buffer_allocator;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simpler method is as follows:

```
Handle<String> code = String::New(
  "(function(arg) {\n\
     console.log(arg);\n\
    })");
Handle<Value> result = Script::Compile(code)->Run();
Handle<Function> function = Handle<Function>::Cast(result);

Local<Value> args[] = { String::New("testing!") };
func->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), 1, args);
```

Essentially compile some code that returns an anonymous function, then call that with whatever arguments you want to pass.

Comment: v8::ScriptCompiler::CompileFunctionInContext does the "wrap your code in a function" bit for you.

Comment: Any chance for an updated version of this code? It doesn't appear to compile with the V8 in 2018.