# Get output from JavaScript function in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, com, iwebbrowser2

Hy,

I'm working at a project that must call from C++ a custom function made in JavaScript. I'm able to run the function

The project should work only on Windows (actually it's a Windows service), so it's ok to use interfaces IWebBrowser2 and IHtmlDocument2

The function's signature is `string function(string)`. I'm able to run the function in C++, based on [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2352/JavaScript-call-from-C) (I'm using IWebBrowser2 and IHtmlDocument2 interface), but I'm not able to get the output from that JS function back in C++.

Is there any method to retrieve the output from that JS function back in C++, using those interfaces? ( or maybe other)

Thank you,

Comment: When you call the function through `Invoke` the return value in placed in a `VARAINT`. It's the 6th parameter to Invoke.

Comment: Do you need to just call a javascript function defined as a text, or a javascript function in a web page context?

Comment: @SimonMourier I need to call just a javascript function defined as a text.

Comment: You can reuse the script engines in Windows, check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/349554/Cplusplus-Win32-and-Scripting-Quick-way-to-add-Scr and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744105/parse-and-execute-js-by-c-sharp (in C# but you can translate it back to c++ where it comes from)

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer to my own question, if someone will have the same question:

Short answer is you can't obtain the output of javascript script using these interfaces. The IWebBrowser2 and IHtmlDocument are running in a context based on IE, so you can't obtain the output of running scripts.

The solutions for this problem are:

- V8 or SpiderMonkey
- [Active Script Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccd0zt2w%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

If you plan to use V8 in your application, the basic example for calling a function is provided at [Calling a v8 javascript function from c++ with an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387015/calling-a-v8-javascript-function-from-c-with-an-argument) (But, be aware of the Dispose() function, which is wrongly placed)

If you plan to use Active Script Interfaces, the basic example is provided at [Run JavaScript function from C++ without MFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846386/run-javascript-function-from-c-without-mfc) . It's a useful example that shows how to run a JavaScript function.