# Using "os" module from native nodejs (electron) C++ code

Tags: node.js, electron, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

I wonder if it is possible to use the "os" module internally in native module, without passing it over as a param from javascript.

It's one of the core nodejs/electron modules so I assume it should be available in native module internally some way or another.

Comment: I don't think any of the C++ code from node's os module is available to link against. You can call JS from C++, but it's by no means efficient -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11387695/1218408 for example. Most of what's in node's OS module is trivial to re-implement.

Comment: Thank you for two nice ideas! If you can provide further info on how to easily grab the OS module functions as C++ native code in the form of an answer, I will gladly accept it )

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

As far as I know, none of node's `"os"` module C++ code is exported for use by other C++ code.

Executing JS from C++ is possible, but far from efficient. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11387695/1218408 for an example of how to do it.)

Most of node's `"os"` module is fairly simple, and you're probably better off re-implementing whatever you need. The source for it is here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node_os.cc

Another possibility is to call your C++ functions with the result of whatever JS function you need. For example, maybe `myFunction(os.loadavg(), "hello")`. Simple but also not super efficient.